# stringi install error: configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: r, stringi

I am trying to install `stringi` package after a recent update of R to newest version. However, I met this error:

> ```
> * installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
> ** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> checking for local ICUDT_DIR... icu55/data
> checking for R_HOME... /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.3/lib/R
> checking for R... /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.3/lib/R/bin/R
> checking for R >= 3.1.0 for C++11 use... yes
> checking for R < 3.4.0 for CXX1X flag use... no
> checking for cat... /bin/cat
> checking for gcc... /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp
> checking whether the C compiler works... no
> configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/y5/m7pd62wn3939vyqxygrd_ff80000gn/T/RtmpNBCRW2/R.INSTALL8ec750ee123/stringi':
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> See `config.log' for more details
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
> * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/stringi’
> Warning in install.packages :
>   installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
> ```

Following some posts, I tried:

```
install.packages('stringi', configure.args='--disable-cxx11')
```

or:

```
install.packages('stringi', type='mac.binary')
```

How could I correctly install `stringi`, did I miss something?

Additional info: I updated R with Homebrew. I successfully installed `data.table` before trying  to install `stringi`, therefore it seems to be caused by package-specific problem.

Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3
```

Comment: See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866862/cannot-install-stringi-since-xcode-command-line-tools-update) and [this github issue](https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/291)

Comment: @Ben, thanks for the link. Didn't follow this after I somehow installed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same problem when updating the `stringi` package. As was stated here https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/291, the issue wasn't with stringi but instead in ~/.R/Makevars. Installation was successful upon deleting this file using `rm ~/.R/Makevars` in your command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about what caused the error. But finally I was able to install `stringi` through following steps:

- remove all versions of `R` installed by homebrew with: `brew uninstall --force r`
- download gfortran(not sure whether this is necessary, just following the installation guide in manual) and R 3.4.3 for Mac OS X from CRAN (I chose .pkg, while .dmg files are also available) and install them.
- open studio and run `install.packages('stringi')`, which seems installed the binary package successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade you compiler, here is an example works on openSUSE:

install newer version of compiler:

```
zypper in gcc7 gcc7-c++ gcc7-c++ gcc7-fortran
```

Edit your compiler config files, open `/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf`, and add following content:

```
CC = gcc-7
CXX = g++-7
CXX98 = g++-7
CXX11 = g++-7
CXX14 = g++-7
CXX17 = g++-7
FC = gfortran-7
F77 = gfortran-7
```

Theoretically, you do not need to restart your R, just install the package you need directly.

Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MacOS your `xcode` license might be expired. Try running:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

from the command line and agreeing with the license.