# "C compiler cannot create executables" when installing stringi in R

Tags: r, clang, openmp, llvm, stringi

I often install R packages from source, and need a properly configured `~/.R/Makevars` to do this. I want to be able to use [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), so I copied a `Makevars` I found online. My `Makevars` ended up being this:

```
OPT_LOC = $(HOME)/homebrew/opt
LLVM_LOC = $(OPT_LOC)/llvm
CC=$(LLVM_LOC)/bin/clang
CXX=$(LLVM_LOC)/bin/clang++

# CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS *with* -fopenmp
CFLAGS=-fopenmp -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-fopenmp -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe

# CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS *without* -fopenmp
# (sometimes the package install process fails if -fopenmp is present)
# CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
# CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe

LDFLAGS=-L$(OPT_LOC)/gettext/lib -L$(LLVM_LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LLVM_LOC)/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I$(OPT_LOC)/gettext/include -I$(LLVM_LOC)/include
```

I can no longer find the original source of my version, but it's similar to [this one](https://luispuerto.net/blog/2018/01/12/install-r-100-homebrew-edition-with-openblas-openmp-my-version/).

My `Makevars` works great, except for a few packages, like stringi. These packages complain that ["C compiler cannot create executables"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010417/stringi-install-error-configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables). I discovered that this error generally goes away if I remove `-fopenmp` from `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. As you can see, I've set up `Makevars` so I can easily switch back and forth between the configuration with `-fopenmp` and without it.

My workaround works fine, as does the workaround of "delete `Makevars` entirely" in the Stack Overflow post linked above. But isn't there a better way? It's annoying that I can't expect package installs to succeed because of these dependencies that hate the `-fopenmp` flag, while removing the flag means I might miss out on OpenMP on some package installs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use GCC instead of Clang you should be able to install stringi with OpenMP enabled. I've tested a number of different solutions and ultimately came up with [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334247/12957340) to successfully install stringi from source with the `-fopenmp` flag (Intel [macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur)):

1. Reinstall the Xcode command line tools (don't believe Software Update if it says 'up to date' - it lies - `brew doctor` said my version was actually old)

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
   sudo xcode-select --install
   ```
2. Install GCC and [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) via Homebrew ([instructions for installing Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)) or, if you already have GCC/LLVM  installed, skip to the next step.

   ```
   # WARNING: This can take several hours
   brew install gcc
   brew install llvm
   ```
3. If you already have GCC and LLVM installed via Homebrew:

   ```
   brew cleanup
   brew update
   brew upgrade
   brew reinstall gcc
   brew reinstall llvm
   ```
4. Link some headers into */usr/local/include*

   ```
   sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/* /usr/local/include/

   # I believe you can safely ignore warnings like this:
   #ln: /usr/local/include//tcl.h: File exists
   #ln: /usr/local/include//tclDecls.h: File exists
   #ln: /usr/local/include//tclPlatDecls.h: File exists
   #ln: /usr/local/include//tclTomMath.h: File exists
   #ln: /usr/local/include//tclTomMathDecls.h: File exists
   #ln: /usr/local/include//tk.h: File exists
   #ln: /usr/local/include//tkDecls.h: File exists
   #ln: /usr/local/include//tkPlatDecls.h: File exists
   ```
5. Edit your `~/.R/Makevars` file (if you don't have a file called `Makevars` in your `~/.R/` directory, create it) and include only these lines:

   ```
   LOC = /usr/local/gfortran
   CC=$(LOC)/bin/gcc -fopenmp
   CXX=$(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp
   CXX11 = $(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp

   CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
   CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
   LDFLAGS=-L$(LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LOC)/lib
   CPPFLAGS=-I$(LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include

   FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
   CXX1X=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
   CXX98=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
   CXX11=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
   CXX14=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
   CXX17=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
   ```
6. Compile a package from source in R/RStudio

   ```
   # Test if OpenMP is actually enabled
   install.packages("data.table", type = "source")
   # (loading data.table will tell you if it was successful)

   # Compile the stringi package from source
   install.packages("stringi", type = "source")
   ```

NB: Some users have commented that they had to install a 'fresh' [GFortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Fortran) (e.g., *[GFortran 10.2 for Big Sur (macOS 11), for Intel processors](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases/tag/10.2-bigsur-intel)*) to compile packages successfully, and others have commented that they didn't need LLVM, but these steps seem to work in most cases.

### Update (2022/04/05)

I recently had an error when updating "RcppAlgos" using this ~/.R/Makevars (couldn't find gmp.h or libgmp). I checked gmp was installed (`brew install gmp`), then added /usr/local/include to CPPFLAGS and /usr/local/lib to LDFLAGS in the ~/.R/Makevars file to solve the problem, and hopefully prevent similar issues in the future, i.e. edit your Makevars to contain these lines only:

```
LOC=/usr/local/gfortran
CC=$(LOC)/bin/gcc -fopenmp
CXX=$(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp
CXX11 = $(LOC)/bin/g++ -fopenmp

CFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native -pipe
LDFLAGS=-L$(LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LOC)/lib,-L/usr/local/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I$(LOC)/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/include

FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
CXX1X=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX98=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX11=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX14=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
CXX17=/usr/local/gfortran/bin/g++
```